# Strange null pointer error in GRAILS addTo

Tags: grails, null, grails-orm

I am coming across a strange error in my GRAILS application.

I have the following two domain classes

```
class IncidentLog {
String log
Date dateCreated
User createdBy
static belongsTo = [incident: Incident]
static constraints = {

    createdBy nullable:true
    log nullable:true
}
```

}

```
class Incident{
static hasMany=[logs:IncidentLog]
}
```

In one of my services I have the following method to save a new log entry

```
def addLog(request){

    Incident incident=Incident.get(request.JSON.id)
    User currentuser=User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)

    IncidentLog logEntry=new IncidentLog(

        log:request.JSON.log,
        createdBy:currentuser

    )


    logEntry.createdBy=currentuser

    incident.addToLogs(logEntry)
    incident.save(failOnError:true)

}
```

For some reason this is throwing a null pointer exception with the following stacktrace

```
2014-05-19 12:13:13,351 [http-bio-8090-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -        NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /MASH/incident/ajaxAddLog
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
Line | Method
->> 1051 | <init>           in java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1204 | <init>           in java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList
|   1190 | unmodifiableList in java.util.Collections
|    223 | ajaxAddLog       in com.saadian.mash.IncidentController
|    200 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in    grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter         in  grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     49 | doFilterInternal in grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.ShiroSubjectBindingFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I have been using GRAILS for a number of years and have never seen this error before any help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Some further information when I first create an Incident I also create an instance of IncidentLog and add it to the logs set and it works with no problems it is only on subsequent attempts to call addTo that it fails.

Comment: NullPointerException is usualy simple debugging problem. Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

initialize your `logs' collection in the domain class:

```
class Incident{
  List logs = []
  static hasMany=[logs:IncidentLog]
}
```

Comment: Ye I initially had done that but it made no difference. Further investigation of the full stack trace showed that the problem was been caused by the auditable plugin that we are using. Once I disabled that it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the plugins you're are using. Especially when you see the error is in a line that does not have null object like `something.save()` (You are sure that `something` is not null and is object of a domain class).

If you're using `org.grails.plugins:audit-logging` like me, you have to put `static auditable = true;` only in the owner/main class, the joins will be handled by the plugin and saved.